# Force open link in same tab?

Tags: macos, safari

In Safari I can hold cmd to open a link in a new tab, I can hold cmd + shift to open in a new tab and focus the new tab, I can hold cmd + alt to open in a new window.

Is there any combination I can hold to forcefully open a link in the same tab? So, if there is a link on the current page that would normally be opened in a new tab (I believe by using `target="_blank"`), can I skip the process of opening it, closing the previous tab, then focussing the newly opened tab?

Lots of sites which try to force you to stay on them by opening every link in a new tab are very frustrating to use. Please let me know if there's a solution so I can force links to open in the current tab when I want them to.

Comment: You can always mouse over the link, _right-click_ **Copy Link** then press: **⌘L ⌘V Enter** Yes it a bit of a pain but once you get use to it, it's quicker than it opening in another window to have to close the other window etc.

Comment: @user3439894 it's not quicker than left click > ⌘⇧[ > ⌘w

Comment: For me the point of forcing opening in same tab is to retain the history, so that I can navigate back to the original page. With the OP's comment, the new tab doesn't remember history. So that's one advantage of @user3439894 proposal.